# Bad practice to have ORMs with NoSQL stores?

Tags: python, orm, nosql, redis, key-value-store

I use Redis ([redis-py](http://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest)) inside my Python platform. Recently it was suggested that I switch to an ORM.

E.g.: [python-stdnet](http://lsbardel.github.io/python-stdnet/), [rom](http://pythonhosted.org/rom/rom.html) or [redisco](https://github.com/iamteem/redisco)

Is use of ORMs considered bad practice in the NoSQL world?

Comment: What would an ORM for Redis even do? Redis is a key-value store.

Comment: I know. The purpose is for an abstracted interface to semantic "Models". I currently have a class called "User", with a bunch of StrictRedis calls. Would it be be bad practise to use (e.g.: [rom](https://github.com/josiahcarlson/rom) || [redisco](https://github.com/kiddouk/redisco) ) in order to make my `User` class more concise + generic?

Comment: I faced a similar issue with Mongoose on node. For No-SQL I think ODM term is more prevalent. I concluded to one thing, "If you think you can do away with it, then don't use it". As for your query, I wouldn't go for it as mentioned by Blender before, its a key-value store. ODMs are useful when you are working on a schema based DB which apparently is far less used in Redis.

Comment: ORM means object **relational** mapper, as in **relational** database. When you deal with non-relational databases like Redis, the term is a misnomer.

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately the question boils down to at what layer do you want to write code.

Do you want to write code that manipulates data structures in a remote database, or do you want to write higher-level code that uses the abstractions built on top of those data structures? You can think of it as a similar question about relational databases as do you want to write SQL, or do you want to write higher-level code?

Personally, despite using `rom` myself for a variety of tasks (I am the author), I also directly manipulate Redis in the same projects where it makes sense.

Comment: I am with this answer. I explored redisco and [this blog](http://tylerstroud.com/2014/11/18/storing-and-querying-objects-in-redis/), this library simply uses redis's functionality but makes storing, retrieving and referencing objects very easy. Ultimately it saves time, though @Josiah, will tell if `rom` is time efficient or not.

Comment: Using rom is reasonably time efficient if you have used ORMs before. It doesn't have joins, so depending on the project may not be the perfect solution for all problems. But I usually start with rom for most new projects.

Answer (score 2):

Comments pointing out that the R in ORM is for relational are technically correct. That doesn't mean there aren't valid uses and reasons for libraries that abstract redis away.

There are some great libraries that make interfacing with a redis feel much nicer and more idiomatic to the language you are using. For ruby libraries like `ohm` or `redis-native_hash` (disclosure: I wrote that one) do just that. For python there are tools like `redisco` and surely others. These make persisting objects to redis very simple and make working with redis feel much more ruby-ish or python-ish.

Here are a few more benefits from using even the most basic abstraction, like a very thin wrapper you might write and keep in your application:

- Switching redis clients will be easier. Maybe you'll never do this, but if you did, changing your calls to redis in one place (your wrapper) is much simpler than changing them everywhere you use redis.
- Implementing things you might need for scaling, like sharding or connection pooling, is likely going to be easier if your calls are made through some abstraction.
- Replacing redis with some other key/value store or data structure server would be simpler if an abstraction is in place.

I'm not advocating using an object mapping library or building your own abstraction, just pointing out there are valid reasons why you would. Its up to you to evaluate your needs and pick what works best for you. There is nothing wrong with calling redis directly either.

Comment: +1 on the abstraction front. The "R" in ORM is more related to Relational Algebra rather than Relational Databases. Relational Algebra defines the ["Projection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)) operation and this can have different implementations depending on the underlying data model. Relational Algebra never specified "TABLE". It specifies data descriptions using the usual mathematical tools for that (sets, tuples, ordered sets, etc).